# undefined reference to variable template of pointer to function in clang but not gcc

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

static constexpr bool isSSE2 = true;

template<typename T>
static void (*fp)();

template<typename T>
static void foo_c() {
    std::cout << "foo_c get called." << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
static void foo_sse2() {
    std::cout << "foo_sse2 get called." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    if (isSSE2)
        fp<int> = foo_sse2<int>;
    else
        fp<int> = foo_c<int>;

    fp<int>();

    return 0;
}
```

I have a project that uses variable template which itself is a pointer to function. The example code above compiles and executes fine in GCC 6.3, but gives warning and error in clang 3.9.1.

```
$ clang++ "Source.cpp" -o "foo.exe" -std=c++14 -O2
Source.cpp:6:15: warning: variable 'fp<int>' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]
static void (*fp)();
              ^
Source.cpp:20:9: note: used here
        fp<int> = foo_sse2<int>;
        ^
1 warning generated.
C:\msys64\tmp\Source-6600e8.o:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to `fp<int>'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `fp<int>();`is a function declaraton??

Comment: In C++14 this was ill-formed; a variable template may not be declared `static`. The latest C++17 draft has changed though.

Comment: The C++17 draft N4618 says it's ill-formed NDR if a static variable template is implicitly-instantiated without being defined, but I can't find anywhere that says whether `template<typename T> static void (*fp)();` is a definition or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to initialize your fp<>() first:

```
template<typename T>
static void (*fp)() = nullptr;
```

It compiles and runs fine in Clang 4.0: [sample code](http://ideone.com/pznunQ). 
And try to always initialize your variables — it may save you from all sorts of headaches. :)